# Alternate plain English algorithm for Towers of Hanoi

Tags: computer-science, puzzle

There are four plain English algorithms for the Towers of Hanoi Puzzle [available on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Iterative_solution), but when I was first solving the puzzle, I came up with an algorithm that is different from any of the solutions I have seen.

Wikipedia algorithms:

1. [Iterative solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Iterative_solution)
2. [Simpler statement of iterative solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Simpler_statement_of_iterative_solution)
3. [Equivalent iterative solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Equivalent_iterative_solution)
4. [Recursive solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Recursive_solution)

Of course the results of the algorithms are the same, and they are really just different ways of thinking about the same thing, but I am talking about plain English ways of describing the process.

My process goes like this:

1. Never move same tile twice in a row(obviously)
2. Prioritize moving right
3. When moving right, move to the closest pole that can be legally moved to.
4. When moving left, move to the farthest pole that can be legally moved to.

..

[image: Towers of hanoi]

These rules differ from other descriptions of the algorithm in that:

- **The initial stack can be placed on any of the 3 pillars and still work without any adjustment to the rules needed.**(Unlike solutions [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Simpler_statement_of_iterative_solution) and [3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Equivalent_iterative_solution) and [4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Recursive_solution))
- **You don't have to number the disks**(Unlike solutions [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Iterative_solution) and [3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Equivalent_iterative_solution) and [4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Recursive_solution))

Has anyone seen this description of the puzzle before?

Comment: Please comment if you down-vote :-\

Comment: I don't think it is right to say that solution 1 requires you to "number the disks". All it requires is that you can distinguish the smallest disk from the rest of the disks. But that's not a question of numbering -- if you can recognize a valid move, you're able to compare the sizes of the disks, and so figure out from scratch for each move which disk is smallest, just by comparing the three _visible_ disks.

Comment: @HenningMakholm That's true. Still, solution one requires adjustments based on the starting direction, where as my solution is unidirectional.

Comment: In fact your description is very closely the same as the one you call solution 1. As Wikipedia points out, the only time you have a choice is when the disk you're moving is the smallest ones, so your rules 2-4 simply drop out of consideration in the moves where you just touched the smallest one. And when you _are_ moving the smallest disk, you can always move it anywhere, so the collected outcome of rules 2-4 is "move it right, wrapping around at the end".

Comment: x @David: Your solution is unidirectional because you don't care which peg the next tower is going to be built on -- following your recipe the location of the next full tower will depend on whether there's an odd or an even number of disks in the game. You could remove the choice of direction from the description of solution 1 too, replacing it with "always move to the right", and get the same outcome.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Ok. That's what I was looking for. If you would post that as an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 1):

In simple language (and note that the *process* is the same, of course):

- (pre-step) Decide on the cyclic sequence of pegs for the smallest disc to move: S-M-D or S-D-M (where "S" denotes source peg, "D" denotes destination peg, and the other peg "M" is the "mid" peg). Choose the first for even towers and the second for odd towers.
- Loop over the following moves:
- ** move the smallest disc on its cycle - if this completes the tower, stop
- ** make the only possible move not involving the smallest disc

Very hard to go wrong following this pair of instructions. And if you happened to pick the wrong cycle, just carry on (after the "null" move that signals a complete tower)  - the tower will move to the correct peg eventually.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is a unidirectional version of the first [iterative solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Iterative_solution).

The difference between the unidirectional solution and the mono-directional version is the unidirectional solution doesn't specify an end position.

> A simple solution for the toy puzzle: Alternate moves between the
>   smallest piece and a non-smallest piece. When moving the smallest
>   piece, always move it to the next position in the same direction (to
>   the right if the starting number of pieces is even, to the left if the
>   starting number of pieces is odd). If there is no tower position in
>   the chosen direction, move the piece to the opposite end, but then
>   continue to move in the correct direction. For example, if you started
>   with three pieces, you would move the smallest piece to the opposite
>   end, then continue in the left direction after that. When the turn is
>   to move the non-smallest piece, there is only one legal move. Doing
>   this will complete the puzzle in the fewest number of moves.

This description of the mono-directional version can be changed to be unidirectional if direction choices of direction are replaced with the rules from the unidirectional solution revolving around prioritizing moving right.